# CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed

Tags: django, i18n, internacionalización

Al querer ejecutar el comando

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en
```

Me muestra lo siguiente:

> CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

Me encuentro usando:

**Windows 7 de 64 Bits**,

**Python 3.4**

**Django 1.11**

Comment: No hay ningún misterio, el error te está diciendo lo que te falta, instalar `gettext`. La página oficial es https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/ y donde pone **precompiled binaries for Windows** te enlaza con https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

En realidad mi objetivo era documentar este "error" para que alguien más pueda instalar el programa en Windows, ya que en Linux se hace por comando. 
Lo que se necesita instalar se conoce como **gettext**.

Por lo que dejo una URL donde puedes instalar dicho programa compilado para Windows y en su versión superior a la 15.

https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html